# Error raised while performing clean install in maven (IntelliJ)

Tags: maven

[cannot access default field of properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GS8r.jpg)

I tried to clean and reinstall and also manually tried to override plugin in Pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

In the right sidebar, you will see the maven tab:
**click it** -> **you'll see something like in the picture** -> **click on generate sources** (the second top icon)

[image]